# Add customer's address to stripe through rails app - monospace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subscription, stripe-payments

I'm about two months in to learning RoR.

Trying to setup a subscription site using https://monospace-rails.herokuapp.com/ and want to add customer's physical address fields to the form. For some reason I can't find any info on this. I'm probably searching the wrong key words.

**This is the user model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :stripe_token, :last_4_digits

  attr_accessor :password, :stripe_token
  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save :update_stripe

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :last_4_digits

  def stripe_description
    "#{name}: #{email}"
  end

  def update_stripe
    if stripe_id.nil?
      if !stripe_token.present?
        raise "We're doing something wrong -- this isn't supposed to happen"
      end

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => email,
        :description => stripe_description,
        :card => stripe_token
      )
      self.last_4_digits = customer.active_card.last4
      response = customer.update_subscription({:plan => "premium"})
    else
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_id)

      if stripe_token.present?
        customer.card = stripe_token
      end

      # in case they've changed
      customer.email = email
      customer.description = stripe_description

      customer.save

      self.last_4_digits = customer.active_card.last4
    end

    self.stripe_id = customer.id
    self.stripe_token = nil
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = self.find_by_email(email)
    if user && BCrypt::Password.new(user.hashed_password) == password
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end


  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm assuming I need to add the address fields to the db, attr_accessible and within the Stripe:: Customer.create add something. I'm a little confused on how to write it and if that is all require to make it work.

Any help or even links in the right direction would be huge.

Comment: You are right. Treat address as a field similar to description field you have in users.

Comment: Thanks @itz2k13 - figured it out